# Python re.sub back reference not back referencing

Tags: python, regex

I have the following:

```
<text top="52" left="20" width="383" height="15" font="0"><b>test</b></text>
```

and I have the following:

```
fileText = re.sub("<b>(.*?)</b>", "\1", fileText, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

In which fileText is the string I posted above. When I print out `fileText` after I run the regex replacement I get back

```
<text top="52" left="20" width="383" height="15" font="0"></text>
```

instead of the expected

```
<text top="52" left="20" width="383" height="15" font="0">test</text>
```

Now I am fairly proficient at regex and I know that it should work, in fact I know that it matches properly because I can see it in the `groups` when I do a search and print out the `groups` but I am new to python and am confused as to why its not working with back references properly

Comment: Usual disclaimer about parsing HTML with regex...

Comment: Not parsing with regex simply removing all bold tags thats all. I have a very limited set of html that is being used and in specific ways in which I know <b> is a leaf node

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to use a [raw-string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) here so that the backslash isn't processed as an escape character:

```
>>> import re
>>> fileText = '<text top="52" left="20" width="383" height="15" font="0"><b>test</b></text>'
>>> fileText = re.sub("<b>(.*?)</b>", r"\1", fileText, flags=re.DOTALL)
>>> fileText
'<text top="52" left="20" width="383" height="15" font="0">test</text>'
>>>
```

Notice how `"\1"` was changed to `r"\1"`.  Though it is a very small change (one character), it has a big effect.  See below:

```
>>> "\1"
'\x01'
>>> r"\1"
'\\1'
>>>
```

Comment: Odd, in neither Python 2 nor 3 it returns the full string for me. I only get the get the replaced text, not the whole string.

Comment: Tested it in the interpreter too, there it works. It doesn't work in an executed file tho. Very odd :P

Comment: Alternatively, a double backslash "\\1" will do.