# How to remove patterned texts surrounding a nested text on a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a text `txt = 'The fat \m{cat sat} on \m{the} mat.'` which I hope to output `'The fat cat sat on the mat.'`

I have tried the following two ways:

```
re.sub(r'\\m\{(.*)\}', '', txt) 
# output: 'The fat  mat.'

re.sub(r'\\m\{(?=.*)\}', '', txt) 
# output: 'The fat \\m{cat sat} on \\m{the} mat.'
```

Why is that and how should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your own regex a bit to make it work

- Use backreference to replace value instead of just empty string
- Also make you regex lazy i.e  `(.*) -> (.*?) or ([^}]*)`

---

```
import re
txt = 'The fat \m{cat sat} on \m{the} mat.';
r = re.sub(r'\\m\{(.*?)\}', "\g<1>", txt);
print(r);      

//The fat cat sat on the mat.
```

Note:- you can use `r"\1"`  or `"\\1"` instead of `\g<1>` to back reference the captured group

Comment: May I ask what ``\g<1>'' means?

Comment: @Tengerye is backreference to captured group, [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: @Tengerye a related question [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765265/python-re-sub-back-reference-not-back-referencing), you can read this also

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this expression

```
\\m{|}
```

replaced with an empty string might work.

#### Test

```
import re

print(re.sub(r"\\m{|}", '', 'The fat \m{cat sat} on \m{the} mat.'))
```

#### Output

```
The fat cat sat on the mat.
```

Comment: That will remove all `}`:s though, not just the ones used in `\m{...}`